# Can LLC's have treasury units?

Tags: corporate-law, florida

I know that corporations that have stock can have treasury stock, but can LLC's have treasury units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if the LLC has elected C-corporation tax treatment.

A pass-through or S-Corp LLC can't be a member of itself because its income has to be attributed to other entities.  (I.e., any attempt to list it as a member would create a recursive loop during tax calculations: The income attributed to the LLC as its own member would then have to be added back to its income and apportioned to all its members, iterating until the income attributed to the LLC "member" is zero.  Which I suppose could make for a fun accounting exercise!)